# How can i use on blur function in AMP?

Tags: javascript, ampscript

I am using amp-script and i want to use on blur function in amp. when i use this in my file .. it is giving error onblur is not a function ..
Basically I want to do this when I touch on my div tag. I want to focus out from my input text.

1 - Html File

```
<amp-script layout="container">
  <input type="text" class="demo-input">
  <button class="demo-button">Try me</button>
     <div id="touch">
       <ul>
          <li>1</li>
          <li>2</li>
          <li>3</li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</amp>
```

2- js File

```
    const touchstart = document.querySelector("touch");
  touchstart.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
    document.querySelector(".demo-input").blur();
  });
```

Please give me some solution 
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the library you're using has a function called blur?

Comment: in the document mention blur() but this is not able to use, always give an error. tired :-(